# Correspondence between routes and html pages in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I do not know how to show the result of my python code in a specific web page. Here is the code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify, make_response
import random
import time

app = Flask(__name__)

# Some irrelevant code here...

db.append([x, " ".join(heading_parts), " ".join(content_parts)])


@app.route("/")
def index():
    """ Route to render the HTML """
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route("/load")
def load():
    """ Route to return the posts """

    time.sleep(0.2)  # Used to simulate delay

    if request.args:
        counter = int(request.args.get("c"))  # The 'counter' value sent in the QS

        if counter == 0:
            print(f"Returning posts 0 to {quantity}")
            # Slice 0 -> quantity from the db
            res = make_response(jsonify(db[0: quantity]), 200)

        elif counter == posts:
            print("No more posts")
            res = make_response(jsonify({}), 200)

        else:
            print(f"Returning posts {counter} to {counter + quantity}")
            # Slice counter -> quantity from the db
            res = make_response(jsonify(db[counter: counter + quantity]), 200)

    return res
```

It compiles perfectly fine and shows the results. My problem is the results of this code is shown in the `index.html`. How can I make them appear in `load.html`?

Comment: Try to return `load.html` instead of res and pass res as a parameter in the load.html. Also just take the value of `res = jsonify(whatever) ` instead of `res=make_response(jsonify(whatever))`

Answer (score 0):

You do not give much details about the `load.html`, but I suggest to Try

```
return redirect(url_for('load.html',res=res))
```

instead of

```
return res
```

and in your `load.hrml` you should have some code to manipulate `res`

In addition, `res` should carry just the `json` data you need to submit and not `response`.